How to find motif in a time series?
Literally the question in the title

So is your question: "given a series of datapoints in a timeseries, what is a way of finding a pattern similar to that, allowing datapoints sampled at a different frequency across the same timeseries?" ?

And for reference your graph does not show the identical structure, it just shows some arbitrary approximation of a shape you have drawn. I.e. You have converted the red box into a series of key feature points and are looking for those feature points on a potentially different sample frequency.

@Attack68 yes, that is my question.

I tested matrix profile as suggested in another answer, but it couldn't find repeating patterns in all scales. The answer was DTW, it needed some configuration changes based on the patterns extracted. Now I'm using many different configurations to find patterns. For future readers, I back-tested this strategy, and the highest win rate I got was 62%, did not worth the effort

Try looking at Matrix Profile (dedicated homepage here). This is designed for exactly your use case.
